# charge pump with bootstrap gate driver

Tags: motor, mosfet-driver, charge-pump, bootstrap

I was building a bootstrap based gate driver for BLDC motor control application.From this application note (https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-HV_Floating_MOS_Gate_Drivers-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626c1f3dc3016c47de609d140a) I came to know that charge pump is required for continuous turning on of high side mosfet.They have demonstrated using a circuit also.But I need some clarity in this regard. [image]
Here it is stated the timer will output a 7.5kHz square wave with 15V amplitude.How is this 7.5kHz designed.?Does this value have any significance.I need to switch my device at 100kHz.Also my Mosfet require a gate voltage of 6V only.So should i use 6V zener to achieve the required amplitude.

Comment: *How is this 7.5kHz designed?* It is not designed, it was **chosen** to be 7.5 kHz, then the circuit (around the ICM755) is designed to work at 7.5 kHz (see its datasheet, the 100 k resistor and 1 nF capacitor are the main components determining the frequency).

Comment: *I need to switch my device at 100kHz* Will you keep switching **continuously** or **stop switching** for longer periods of time? If your switching is continuous, you do not need the chargepump circuit with the ICM755. You can then use the standard bootstrap circuit using a diode.

Comment: *my Mosfet require a gate voltage of 6V only* Is that the **maximum** allowed \$V_{GS}\$ of your MOSFET? Or do you have reasons to use 6 V? (If so, explain those reasons). If the MOSFET can handle more than 6 V there is generally no problem with applying a higher \$V_{GS}\$ to the MOSFET.

Comment: If your drive is 100 kHz then you don't need the 666 timer circuit.

Comment: As Andy said, you could limit the DT ratio to be 90% max. and you don't need the timer.

Comment: Hi all..My 100kHz switching is for normal operation.At times I may need to supply continuous drive without switching.For that i need this charge pump circuitry.Also I am using GaN device which supports maximum 6V gate charge only.